# Why is my server returning JSON, but the frontend receives it as HTML?

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, express, heroku

I'm making an API call to WP REST and returning some data. I'm returning JSON from my express server but the react frontend is receiving it as HTML and as a result, my app is crashing. How do I ensure the frontend receives JSON too?

#### Already tried...

- Setting headers 'Content-type' : 'application/json'
- Sending the data from the backend as res.json() instead of res.send() (hail mary of course)
- Sending a GET request from Postman to confirm it's returning JSON

#### The code on the frontend

```
fetch('/ingredients')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((ingredients: IIngredient[]) => updateIngredients(ingredients))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

#### The code on the backend

```
router.get('/ingredients', async (req, res) => {
      await request.get(`${process.env.BASE_API_URL}/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=${process.env.CONSUMER_KEY}&consumer_secret=${process.env.CONSUMER_SECRET}&category=35&type=simple&per_page=30`)
        .then(res => res.body)
        .then((ingredients: IIngredient[]) => ingredients.map(ingredient => {
          ingredient.rank = 0;
          ingredient.previouslyRanked = false;
          return ingredient;
        }))
        .then((ingredients: IIngredient[]) => res.send(ingredients))
        .catch((error: Error) => res.json({ error }))
    });
```

#### Expected results

With the code above, i'd expect JSON data to be returned on the frontend, locally and in production.

#### Error message received when deployed to Heroku (Somehow it's fine locally??)

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: tried sending with `res.json(ingredients)` instead of `res.send(ingredients)`?

Comment: already tried that - i also mention i've already tried that in the question details

Comment: `res.send(JSON.stringify(ingredients))`

Comment: Just tried this and it's still failing

Comment: I guess the problem with API response at backend. Can you please test the heroku API with postman?

Comment: set a content-type to application/json and test it again

Comment: @ClueMediatorit doesn't return the data - just the javascript page?

Comment: You probably have error on server which returns some HTML containing the error.